# What is more efficient in C# - hardcoding 41 modifiers, or solving that through maths?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, dice, dd

I'm a really beginning coder who wants to port Dungeons & Dragons OGL mechanics to my Unity3D project.
Now, I want to have modifiers for basic Character Attributes in C#.
These are based around number 10/11, which are the "middle" results on 20-sided dice.
Base Characters Attributes are for example Strength, Intelligence, Charisma etc.
The higher your stats are above 10, the higher stat modifier you get. The lower from 10, the lower your modifier (negative one).

```
So, for 10 and 11 you have +0 (no modifer). Now, for:
12, 13 -> you get +1
14, 15 = +2
16, 17 = +3
18, 19 = +4
20, 21 = +5
22, 22 = +6 and so on (Character Attributes can go up to 40 and as low as 0 I guees)

For attributes below average, so below 10:
8, 9 = -1
6, 7 = -2
4, 5 = -3
2, 3 = -4
0, 1 = -5
```

Now, I could hardcode it on ifs or like one folk, on switches. This is part of his code:

```
private string DetermineModNum(string value)
{
    int score; //convert to int.
    TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Integer, null, out score);
    if (score > 10)
    {
        if (score % 2 == 0) //can be divided by 2
        {
            switch (score)
            {
                case 12:
                    return "1";
                case 14:
                    return "2";
                case 16:
                    return "3";
                case 18:
                    return "4";
                case 20:
                    return "5";
                case 22:
                    return "6";
                case 24:
                    return "7";
                case 26:
                    return "8";
                case 28:
                    return "9";
                case 30:
                    return "10";

            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (score)
            {
                case 11:
                    return "0";
                case 13:
                    return "1";
                case 15:
                    return "2";
                case 17:
                    return "3";
                case 19:
                    return "4";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (score % 2 == 0) //can be divided by 2
        {
            switch (score)
            {
                case 10:
                    return "0";
                case 8:
                    return "-1";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (score)
            {
                case 9:
                    return "-1";
                case 7:
                    return "-2";
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is incomplete and just part of his character generator.
But the other way to do it would be probably to divide the Attribute by 4. So instead of writing it all, we could divide our stats by 4.

For example:
Strength: 7 (modifier would be 7 / 4 = 1,75, so we should round it up to 2 and change it to -2)
Intelligence: 18 (modfier would be 18 / 4 = 4,5, so that's just int 4)

Which approach would be faster in a Unity3D game?

Also, if second solution is better, could you help me showing how to construct it best in C#? I'm just learning, could really use some good example here. I need modifiers below 10 to be - and above to be +, with a range of attributes at about 0 - 40 at least (will check max Attribute in SRD soon).

I will need a lot of modifiers based on different things. Some will be easy and regular like above, some have other patterns of modifiers, like every 2nd level, but some other things, like class abilities, will have custom, but sometimes still repetitive patterns.

All mechanics must be as fast as possible because during combat all is calculated real-time and I want to have best performance possible.

Comment: Don't prematurely optimise.  The maths for deriving ability modifiers is incredibly simple and isn't ever going to impose a performance penalty.

Comment: "Which approach would be faster in a Unity3D game?" You'll have to try it both ways to be certain.

Comment: I'm going to guess that using strings instead of actual ints is by far the worst performance hit in that code.

Comment: How about building a static array of 30 integers at startup?  Then getting the modifier for a given value should be lightening fast.

Comment: @LorentzVedeler Yeah, that's absolutely true.  There is no reason for them to be `string`s, they should just be `int`s.  They should be converted to strings only if needed for display logic.

Comment: Learning from you guys, thanks. I think I'll use arrays for some irregular patterns, where there is no way to shortcut it or it isn't worth it. And for things like equipment, lists of skills, etc. Here a simple calculation would be enough I guess, would save a lot of space so if commented, it's better readable.

Comment: Heck, maybe even Enums for those custom things like getting bonuses at custom levels (for example, it could be a spell effect - that you get some bonus at weird levels, like only on 2, 3, 5, 7,8, etc, for balancing reasons).

Comment: Hi Sarr, it is inconceivable you will have any performance issues.  You are out by about a factor of ***ten million***.  So you can forget that.  Today, you must program for ***clarity*** (code clarity), that is the only concern in engineering today.

Comment: Ok, got it, thank Joe Blow :). You are all extremely helpful here, I am really impressed by how you approach newbies' questions. Makes you want to be a coder for real and join this great community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integer arithmetic is very fast on modern CPUs. On the other hand conditional jumps can empty the execution pipeline and slow down the execution. So doing math can possibly be faster than a lengthy switch statement. Math will also be much more concise and less error prone than 2 screen full of case statements.

But I guess that you will barely notice any difference between the different approaches. And don't forget: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

So

```
int modNum = (score / 2) - 5;
```

is clearly to be preferred. Note that here an integer division is performed, which automatically truncates the result. E.g.  `13 / 2 ==> 6`.

`short`'s (16-bit), `int`'s (32-bit) and `long`s (64-bit) all store integer, i.e. whole numbers having no fractional part.

Comment: This looks briliant to me.So I guess it could properly calculate every modifier. But what about score 1 or 0? We should have -5 for both values. Won't integer type break it, will it really show 0? I don't know how it works yet. So int is just for a result of maths which can contain floats during calculations? Even inside that int?

Comment: (10/2)-5 = 0, (11/2)-5 = 0,  (12/2)-5 = 1,   (13/2)-5 = 1,   (14/2)-5 = 2,   (15/2)-5 = 2, ...

Comment: A calculation involving only ints will **always** return ints! `9/2 = 4`, `9/2.0 = 4.5`, `9.0/2 = 4.5`. You can also get the rest of the division with the modulo operator `9 % 2 = 1`. So `(9/2)*2 + 9 % 2) = 9`. `float` and `double` can have decimals. `int` and `long` not.

Comment: Yes, so it will properly calculate int modNum = ( 1 / 2 ) - 5; ? It should return -5 to be like in rulebooks. So I guess more complicated way, like this: score = (score - score % 2) / 2 - 5;  isn't neccesary, it's the same? I mean, only the result of calculation must an int, but decimals are included in calculations leading to this resulting int.

Comment: 1/2 = 0, (1/2)-5 = -5. With (9/2)*2 + 9 % 2) = 9 I only show that the two operations `/` and `%` are complementary and that you can reverse the operation 9/2 by multiplying with 2 again and add the rest (9%2). You will only need `(score/2)-5`. It will always work. Make a small console app and try it out.

Answer (score 3):

You could get rid of the huge switch statement with the simple calculation:

```
float value = Mathf.Floor(score/2) - 5;
return value.ToString();
```

Worrying about optimizations like this at this stage is silly though. Profile your game after you have something concrete or if you notice any obvious performance issues.

Edit: as said in the comments. The `Mathf.Floor` is unnecessary. The integer value will be truncated (Rounded down) automatically.

Comment: Since `score` is an `int`, `Math.Floor` is superfluous.

Comment: Well, but wouldn't it be a good practice? Maybe better to try and use fastest methods from the start, so you won't have as many surprises?
But yeah, I'm learning from you all here, just trying to get a picture how you'd do it.

Comment: I thought it might be beneficial for the OP to understand the calculation. It might not be clear that the int would be truncated otherwise. @Sarr Leaving Out the `Mathf.Floor` would be marginally faster (I think). But it's a tiny micro optimisation. If you understand how a `float` is cast to and `int` implicitly then leave it out.

Comment: @Sarr No, it's not good practise.  It's good practise to write simple code that is likely to be correct first.  There is no point writing a huge and overcomplicated function that is very easy to get wrong when there is almost definitely no measurable performance gain from doing so.  Develop your application first, then profile and replace performance bottlenecks with optimised code at the end.

Comment: Ok, got it, you're great guys. So probably something like this would be most concise form: int modNum = (score / 2) - 5; Now I should just decide either to make an array or this calculation. Seems calculation would be best here, as it's a constant, core mechanic. Arrays would be for some irregular modifiers, like getting something at level 3rd, 5th, 6th, 8th and 9th.

Comment: HI @sarr.  Read this "Maybe better to try and use fastest methods from the start, so you won't have as many surprises".  now read this: ***You are wrong***.  You seem to be having trouble accepting what folks are saying.  If you have an inflexible viewpoint, you'll find it tough to learn software engineering.  You ***must not*** concern yourself with performance - only with coding clarity.

Comment: No, I was just curious :). I'm sure it's good practice to understand exactly why it should be that way. And you have explained it to me on this page clearly. I agree, this was a great advice.

Answer (score 2):

Case statements are lengthy, while math computations may be hard to follow (although in your case they look quite simple).

A very flexible approach is to build a look-up table, populate it with answers, and get the result with a simple loop-up into the array:

```
private static int[] ModNumByScore = new [] {
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-2,-1,-1,
    0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4,
    5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0,
   10
};
private static string DetermineModNum(string value) {
    int score; //convert to int.
    if (!TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Integer, null, out score)) {
        // Throw an exception: the string is invalid
    }
    if (score > 30 || score < 7) {
        // Throw an exception: the score is invalid
    }
    return ModNumByScore[score].ToString();
}
```

Now you can populate your table the way you wish, and the readers of your code would be able to tell what's being returned for each score by looking at the number in the table.

Comment: @ErikForbes Ah, of course! I added an example to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: So you suggest to make an array?
But I won't base it on that code I mentioned, we need it like I wrote above that - stats range from 0 to 40 at least (maybe higher because of magic items, etc). So mods would be from -5 to +10 or more.
Maybe best not to set any limits at this point, so I guess we can remove  "    if (score > 30 || score < 7) {  
        // Throw an exception: the score is invalid  
    }."

Comment: @Sarr Look-up tables of 40 items are pretty small. The only reason you need limits is to catch too high/too low scores early. If you remove the limits, .NET is going to trap scores that are too high with an array index out of bound exception.

Comment: Great, thank you. This is really helpful. But I guess it could be better to make this a calculation like "int modNum = (score / 2) - 5;" and i could use arrays for some irregular things, like bonuses on 4th, 8th, 10th level, etc. In array I can make it 100% custom, calculations would be for constant predictable logics.

Comment: @Sarr That's exactly the right observation: when the formula is easy to understand (say, half the value minus five) then formula is easier to read and write; when formula would be too hard, or you need 100% custom values, look-up table is easier to read and write.

Answer (score 1):

Performance differences are probably negligible, and the math is very simple for this:

```
score = (score - score % 2) / 2 - 5;
```

The first thing you want to do is handle pairs of consecutive numbers as the same number. This can be easily achieved by subtracting the modulo of 2 from the original number.
Then you divide the result by 2 to get consecutive numbers again. 
After that all you have to do is subtract 5 from this to get the equation you started with:

> ...
>   8, 9 => -1
>   10, 11 => 0
>   12, 13 => 1
>   ...

Comment: Darn, I wasn't very good at maths to start with and don't remember how modulo works (I'm Polish, maybe we just called it otherwise). This looks interesting though, could you explain me that part "- score % 2"? I get it how you explained in text, but don't get maths behind it.

Comment: `modulo` returns the rest of a division. E.g. `10 % 3 = 1`.

Comment: It is not necessary to remove the rest of the division beforehand, because the integer division truncates the result anyway. `(score - score % 2) / 2 == score / 2`.